# Internal Error with Lambda function and MSK service

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-msk

```
Batch size: 100
Last processing result: PROBLEM: Lambda internal error. Please contact Lambda customer support.
Starting position: TRIM_HORIZON
```

We have a lambda function that consumes a MSK (kafka server) messages. It is working without problem.
But sometimes it stopped working with no reason (no logs) and only shows:

> PROBLEM: Lambda internal error. Please contact Lambda customer
> support.

We log almost each line of code (lambda function), There is no error.

We don't have paid support service. But I think if it is related to internal AWS error, They must provide free support. Anyways, Can we solve it?